# PushKit VOIP Push , in a VOIP App. Mixed usage with normal type push?

Tags: ios, voip, pushkit

I am developing a VOIP app, and planning to use PushKit as our push engine. We are using it to send VOIP related push to application, allowing us to setup the call.

However, are we allowed to use the same push engine for other type of messages? like a trigger to refresh news, local database, etc in the background thread.

I mean will they approve this kind of "mixed usage" on app store?

Thanks

Comment: Yes because you are using pushkit for VoIP call also so I guess no issue about mixed usage.

Answer (score 0):

Starting on iOS 13, you are no longer able to do so.

Now you must always report a new incoming call when you receive a voip push notification. Not doing so will cause a crash. Repeatedly failing to do so will make your app ignore subsequent voip pushes.